# JS assigning an array to a new variable causes edits to affect both arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, variable-assignment

In this JavaScript bit, I try to make a copy of an array.

```
var array1=[1,1,2,1];
var array2 = array1;
println(array1);
array2[0]=0;
println(array1);
println(array2);
```

It returns the following

```
1,1,2,1
0,1,2,1
0,1,2,1
```

Why does changing array2 also change array1? Shouldn't it be a completely separate array with the same contents? How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

to make copy you should spread an array

```
var array2 = [...array1]
```

Now you have two different arrays

the way you do you just assign a link to the same object